# Error when using cosmosdb java sdk ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am using azure-cosmosdb 2.6.1 version dependency to connect to cosmosdb from spring boot application.

When i try to initialize asyncdocumentclient, I am getting the error 
`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA` and the client is not getting initialized. Can u plz help me in fixing this issue

The same is working when i run the application from commandline, but when I use IntellijIDEA IDE its not working. I tried reimporting the dependencies but it is not working.

Stacktrace:

````
1 = {StackTraceElement@11191} "com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.rx.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl.<clinit>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:132)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@11192} "com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.rx.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:224)"```
````